# Vuejs Error while loading mediainfo.js package

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, mediainfo

We have one we application where we record video for 30sec or 1 min and submit to server. The device can be anything.

When we do record from laptop for 30sec the size of the video is 60mb, if from latest iphone size is 180.

Our server loads video if the video size is less than 60mb

to fix this issue, i tried compressing video in front end using this example [enter link description here](https://tsubasa.netlify.app/) which uses vuejs.

We are using vuero framrwork.

Tsubasa [enter link description here](https://tsubasa.netlify.app/) using mediainfo.js package. I followed same code but i am facing this issue..

The issue is :

**MediaInfoModule.wasm net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/node_modules/mediainfo.js/src/mediainfo.ts (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)**

Please check screenshot

[image]

My nodemodule structure as below, plugin we have added in vite.config.ts file

[image]

I researched on this issue try to fix but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to tell exactly what you need to change as we don't see the relevant code.

Make sure the file `MediaInfoModule.wasm` can be loaded in the browser. Check the browsers network tab. It tells you where your frontend expects the file.

Note, that you can also set the file location explicitly using `locateFile` as shown [in this example](https://github.com/buzz/mediainfo.js/blob/0b18458780338eeefa829be48781cfc017503ee3/examples/browser-simple/example.js#L37).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of *mediainfo.js*.

Comment: After `npm install mediainfo.js`  I can not use globally in my project. It say cant read mediainfo.js , is this because we are using vue and vuero framework ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you here without seeing any code. I gave general instructions how to solve your issue. Can you please provide a full example by adding a CodePen? Thank you.

Comment: As the project is not small I cannot put in code pen. I will try best to explain the problem. We use Vuejs and Vuero framework.  We have folder structure ``src>job>jobOpening.vue `` so if I try to access ``mediainfo.js`` inside ``jobOpening.vue`` it say cannot find this file. To solve this I put the configuration in ``vite.config.ts`` please check screenshot in main question. Then also it says not found, when I create ``jobOpening.vue`` in direct ``src--root folder`` it is working..Why it is stopping me to access from sub directories ?  I wish you understand the problem.

Comment: Please provide vuejs example in github ``mediainfo.js``. Its very much needed for me. I was fixing v8 issues, when i did ``npm install mediainfo.js`` again due to some reason, ``mediainfo.js v9`` comes up, there is no documentation what has changes, all of sudden the issues I fixed on v8 has gone. Now I dont know what has changed and what to update in my code.